# Flash SOUND_COMPLETE event glitch?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, events, audio

I have an intro.AIF file and a loop.aif file embedded in Flash, I need to play the intro then play the loop. So this is what I did

```
var intro:introSound = new introSound();
var introChannel:SoundChannel = intro.play();
introChannel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, handleAudioLoop);

private function handleAudioLoop($event:Event):void {
var loop:loopSound = new loopSound();
var loopChannel:SoundChannel = loop.play(1, int.MAX_VALUE);
}
```

What happened was that it's not seamless, there seems to be some kind of glitch or pop before the loop even begins. Then I tried to use settimeout since I thought the problem is the eventListener, but still can't get it perfect, it's either the pop sound or I'll have to play the loop just slightly earlier.

Has anyone ever had this problem and know how to solve it? Thanks.

ps. playing both sound files back to back in iTune is seamless, just not in Flash.

Answer (score 0):

If your sound is in mp3 format, there is always blank space before  and after every track. If you have the sound file in the FLA, replace the mp3 file with a wav file and Flash will automatically convert it to mp3 format without the blank spaces.

Comment: Here's some more info about this MP3 gap problem that is torturing Flash developers since ages: http://blog.andre-michelle.com/2010/playback-mp3-loop-gapless/

Answer (score 0):

Event.SOUND_COMPLETE is not precise enough to play different sounds seamlessly unfortunately. Have a look at [Prefered method for looping sound flash as3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227442/prefered-method-for-looping-sound-flash-as3)